# User birthday and location is not coming in facebook api for website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried to add Facebook credential to my website. But date-of-birth and location are not returned.

```html
<?php
include_once("includes/config.php");
include_once("includes/access_login.php");
include_once("facebook/facebook.php");
 define('APP_KEY','01806355599654652640');
 define('SECREATE_KEY','05a2ddre1332f5e7e9dc993026ac5966507b70');
$Fb = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => APP_KEY,
    'secret' => SECREATE_KEY
));
$session = $Fb->getUser();
 if (!$session) {
    $params = array(
        'scope'  => "user_about_me,user_location,user_hometown,user_birthday,email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,user_photos,friends_photos"
    );
    header("location:".$Fb->getLoginUrl($params));
    die();
} 
$Fb->setExtendedAccessToken();
$access_token = $Fb->getAccessToken();
$userInfo = $Fb->api('/me');
echo "<pre>";
pr($userInfo);exit;
```

Suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

The birthday is in the "Extended Profile".  The other fields are in the "Public Profile".  Public profiles can be accessed without review.  Extended ones require special review and permissions for each app.

Here is a quote from the facebook developer site at:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/user

From Facebook :

> user_birthday
>
> Access the date and month of a person's birthday. This may or may not
>   include the person's year of birth, dependent upon their privacy
>   settings and the access token being used to query this field.
>
> Please note most integrations will only need age_range which comes as
>   part of the [[public_profile]](https://eu4.proxysite.com/process.php?d=x5B99EqdCF1eiNvaR0SdiMVFMnkPhWA8rcq6jy6Ev%2BHpEWSjbWs1SGEB5x%2FmxOTCDV3lliUviPgdpmg%3D&b=3) permission.

**Review**

> If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to [review](https://eu4.proxysite.com/process.php?d=x5B99EqdCF1eiNvaR0SdiMVFMnkPhWA8rcq6jy6Ev%2BHpFnWweyYoQnxF7geuweWKFFY%3D&b=3) how
>   your app uses it.
>
> When submitting for review, please be clear as to why age_range is not
>   sufficient for your use case. Common Usage
>
> Provide age relevant content to people based on their date of birth
>   information.
>
> Provide age relevant content for anything where the age range is not
>   sufficient.
>
> Determine whether a person says they are under 18, over 18 or over 21.
>   Please use the age_range field which is provided as a part of the
>   public_profile permission, for which no review is needed before use.